# Where is the plugins directory for Turnkey Trac?

Tags: ldap, trac, turnkey-linux

I setup a Turnkey Trac virtual machine and am trying to set up the [LdapPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/LdapPlugin) to use use authentication through a local Active Directory. I tried using

```
easy_install http://trac-hacks.org/svn/ldapplugin/
```

to install it and it claimed to have completed, however when I go to the Admin page and go to plugins, it is not listed. I have never setup a Turnkey server like this before and was wondering in which directory the Trac plugins are located on the Turnkey-linux machine?

Thanks,

Tomek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that you can find it by SSH-ing into the server and running

```
find / -name "trac.ini"
```

This will give you the location of the .ini files for each of the Trac projects. It is in these folders that you will find the plugins folder.

My files were located in: /var/local/lib/trac